# How do I write the code to this simple statement in C?

Tags: c, nodes

I have a linked list of nodes which have two integers an up and down value, I want to make a loop that checks each node after the first, and checks to see if the up and down values are the same on any of the other ones. I just do not know the function names in C to do this, is there a length of method, or is there a way I can just say while the next node is not null? I figured it has to be something like this, but sorry ahead of time, this is the second time I have ever looked at C in my life. This is kind of pseudocode of what I need, can anyone point me in the right direction or give me any tips?

```
while(nextNode != null)
{
  if(currentNodes.up == nextNodes.up && currentNodes.down== nextNodes.down):
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
 }
```

Comment: One issue: `else:` and `while(...):` and `if(...):` should not have the colons.

Answer (score 2):

You'll also need  some form of updates to the current and next nodes.

For example let's say you have this node:

```
struct node;
struct node {
    int up;
    int down;
    struct node *next;
};
```

And then you main code:

```
/*
* 0 implies false (no clashes) and 1 implies true (clash found).
* Assuming headNode points to the first node in the list.
*/
int checkStuff(struct node *headNode) {
    if(headNode == NULL) {
        return 0;
        //Or return 1 depending on how you want to handle this corner case.
    }
    struct node *nextNode = headNode->next;
    while(nextNode != NULL) {
        if(headNode->up == nextNode->up && headNode->down == nextNode->down) {
            return 1;
        }
        nextNode = nextNode->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This would currently just compare currentNode with all following nodes; you'll need to rework your loop if you're looking for something else.

Comment: I have the struct that defines the node in a different file, so if I were instead passing it in as a parameter to a function that was to do this, would I just put say struct node* as the parameter?

Comment: Also just because I have never used C before, the things you're saying are kind of confusing. Is currentNode an actual thing you can call in C, referring to the current node, or is it something that I would have to define?

Comment: @JoshBurkman: It's something you'd have to define. That's a node that would be the first (non-null) node.

Comment: Okay, then I guess my real question is this. If I passed in the pointer to a node, how do I make a loop to traverse through the next nodes until one of them is null? Like how do I get it to go from one node to the next node? The whole syntax of C is just really throwing me off.

Comment: @JoshBurkman: Could you edit your struct into the body of the question? I'm shooting in the dark without it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97049/discussion-between-roney-michael-and-josh-burkman).

Comment: regarding this line: `while(nextNode != null) {`,  `null` should be `NULL`